# C# - Using WiFiAdapter.ConnectAsync Method to connect to specific access point is unreliable

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, connection, wifi

When using the WiFiAdapter.ConnectAsync Method from the Windows.Devices.WiFi namespace, and attempting to connect to a specific wifi access point retrieved through the WiFiAdapter.ScanAsync Method, it doesn't always connect to the access point enumerated through the WiFiAvailableNetwork Class. Instead, it usually connects to the Access Point with the best connection.

```cs
private async void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedNetwork = ResultsListView.SelectedItem as WiFiNetworkDisplay;
            if (selectedNetwork == null || firstAdapter == null)
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser("Network not selcted", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
                return;
            }
            WiFiReconnectionKind reconnectionKind = WiFiReconnectionKind.Manual;
            if (IsAutomaticReconnection.IsChecked.HasValue && IsAutomaticReconnection.IsChecked == true)
            {
                reconnectionKind = WiFiReconnectionKind.Automatic;
            }

            WiFiConnectionResult result;
            if (selectedNetwork.AvailableNetwork.SecuritySettings.NetworkAuthenticationType == NetworkAuthenticationType.Open80211 &&
                selectedNetwork.AvailableNetwork.SecuritySettings.NetworkEncryptionType == NetworkEncryptionType.None)
            {
                result = await firstAdapter.ConnectAsync(selectedNetwork.AvailableNetwork, reconnectionKind);
            }
            else
            {
                // Only the password portion of the credential need to be supplied
                var credential = new PasswordCredential();

                // Make sure Credential.Password property is not set to an empty string. 
                // Otherwise, a System.ArgumentException will be thrown.
                // The default empty password string will still be passed to the ConnectAsync method,
                // which should return an "InvalidCredential" error
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NetworkKey.Password))
                {
                    credential.Password = NetworkKey.Password;
                }

                result = await firstAdapter.ConnectAsync(selectedNetwork.AvailableNetwork, reconnectionKind, credential);
            }

            if (result.ConnectionStatus == WiFiConnectionStatus.Success)
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser(string.Format("Successfully connected to {0}.", selectedNetwork.Ssid), NotifyType.StatusMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser(string.Format("Could not connect to {0}. Error: {1}", selectedNetwork.Ssid, result.ConnectionStatus), NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
```

I would expect to be able to connect to the wifi access point with the BSSID in the associated WiFiAvailableNetwork class being passed to the ConnectAsync() method.

Comment: Can you tell us what equipment you tested?

Comment: What do you mean by equipment? It's a standard Windows 10 1903 laptop and the access points vary in make and model. Some are Cisco, others TP-LINK, etc.

Comment: When I tested, it worked well. It always connects to the specified network. So can you provide a simple sample that can reproduce this issue?

Comment: Hi Faywang -- I found another solution. WiFiAdapter doesn't let you specify the specific Access Point within a given network. The best way to specify a specific Access Point / BSSID is through NativeWifi. Fortunately I already have an Application Bridge in this project, because that requires a non-UWP app.

Comment: It's great. And you can post the answer directly, that would be helpful for other communities who meet the same problem.